# How can I rotate a video by a few degrees?

Tags: video, video-editor

I've taken a fairly tilted video and want to rotate it to be level, how can I do this? I'm open to any third-party apps but purely apple solutions are better.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using FCPX, a [Transform effect](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12604?locale=en_US) will do the trick.

Using FCP 7, you can access rotation along with scale and position in the [Motion tab](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=66%26section=2%26tasks=true) of the Viewer.